# How to see what's making SQL Server grow after starting and not doing anything else

Tags: sql-server, memory, sql-server-2008-r2

When I start SQL Server it won't stop growing and gets to over a gigabyte within a couple minutes.  I have restarted the service several times and each time it does the same thing.  After each time I restarted the service I do not start any applications and have no applications open that would use SQL Server.

1. I turned the SQL Agent off just to make sure it wasn't running anything.
2. I've tried seeing if the profiler would show anything being run but didn't see anything.
3. I tried running a query to see what the longest running queries were but nothing seems out of order there either.

I'm wondering what other options I have to try and figure out what's causing SQL Server to grow incessantly?

Comment: What is growing? Memory usage? Disk usage? CPU utilization? Network traffic?

Comment: What kind of SQL Server? Microsoft? Someone else's?

Comment: For `MS SQL Server` - It tries to cache as much to memory as possible, and will use as much memory as is available.  This enables it to resolve queries as quickly as possible.  You can limit this memory usage, but than you are limiting it's ability to cache.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

Comment: If it's memory utilization, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47434

Comment: Memory usage is growing to over a gig within a couple minutes and just keeps growing.

Comment: @radomaj Sorry, sql server 2008 r2.  I've got it tagged now.

Comment: @MatBailie That statement is simply not true. SQL Server will not try to cache as much memory as possible. It simply uses what it needs to in order to fullfill the queries being tossed at it. Your own link basically says so: "SQL Server is not guaranteed to allocate the amount of memory specified in min server memory. If the load on the server never requires allocating the amount of memory specified in min server memory, SQL Server will run with less memory."

Comment: @MatBailie I do understand how SQL generally uses as much memory as it has access to when caching data, however I can't tell that anything is actually running queries against SQL to make it need to do so in the first place.  That's the real problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @BVernon - What makes you think queries need to be happening for SQL Server to Cache?  In the most naive sense it could just attempt to load all tables and stats into memory.  It will also have stats on previous queries which it can load on a re-start, it then uses those stats to determine a best-guess as to what data to pre-fetch.  In short, it will and should grow as much as possible to fill the available memory, even with no external activity of any kind.

Comment: @MatBailie When you first start SQL, it does not simply pre-fetch gigabytes worth of data for you when you aren't doing anything.  It's currently up to 10gb and still growing.  There isn't even 10gb worth of information that would be called at once unless it's pre-fetching the last 3 years worth of data.  Pretty sure that's not happening.

Comment: @BVernon - Why are you pretty sure of this?  If it has available memory to utilise why wouldn't it just keep pre-fetching more and more?

Comment: @MatBailie Because I've been using SQL Server for years and it's never done this before.  Why would it just start exhibiting different behavior out of the blue one day?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure max memory usage: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

Comment: Not just "can" - you **should** do this. If you don't, there's a very real chance that the OS will become memory-starved & start swapping to disk. And that's not good for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to see what SQL Server is caching in RAM then have a look at the sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors DMV:

[sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173442.aspx)

This DMV will return a row for every single page in the buffer pool, it will tell you what type of page it is and it will tell you which database it belongs to.

The other thing in SQL Server that can eat RAM is the plan cache, which you can see by referencing the associated DMV (sys.dm_exec_cached_plans) and the associated functions around this.

There are loads of resources available on how to use these DMVs to analyse the contents of the plan cache and buffer pool, so you will be able to tell exactly what SQL Server is using all this memory for.

The previous answer is correct though, you really do need to set the max server memory property to prevent SQL Server running away with all the RAM, especially in this case where it appears to be a concern.